# How to direct CMake to use libraries in specific directory only

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake

I am trying to get all dependent libraries in my project in one directory and read from only that directory in CMake. I want to do this so that I may have portability of my project and so that it can run on any computer as long as that directory with all the libraries is present with the executable. Is this possible somehow? I am using Ubuntu 14.10.

I have a LOT of static libraries used in my project and they are in places such as usr/lib, usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu, usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems that you need to use **link_directories** to tell where to find your libs.

Comment: I did that however the project still seems to pick up only the libs in the system folders. Im sorry im new to CMake.

Comment: Maybe you need to link the files manually, than. link_directories, should do the trick because it tells what other directories to look up.

Comment: maybe you mean target_link_directories. You're probably getting down-voted for advocating what should be deprecated methods.